# android disable recent apps Key

Tags: android, android-launcher

I have a custom home app a launcher

so i have control on home key back key and menu key i do what i need but on my tablet a 10.1" IPS Dual Core of Artview i have 4 button

-the back, one with a arrow
-the home, one with a little house
-the recent apps, who look like 2 superposed box (and who on press show recent app)
-the menu, 3 little point

My probleme is i wan't to do a custom think on the 3rd button but android systeme don't let me...

Anyway to do that? And if i have 4 button maybe i don't use the right keycode for the second one

Comment: how do you control the home key?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have finally found a way to do this

No doc about this do it on the onCreate of your activity

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(8);
```

But the 8 is a hidden flag to completly disable system UI with this your app is permanly in full screen(Be carefull if you use this bind power buton to exit app :P)

And don't forget 
    android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR
in your manifest

Don't k now if work in every version of android try on 4.0 4.1 and it's work for 3.x don't know.

Comment: This solution is awesome, I have tried it in 4.2.2 and it works! Thanks!

Comment: this is not the useful code, i tried to disable recent apps list button, but did not get any success, my tab supports kitkat